# checks if node is the root of a binary search tree.

Tags: c++, c++14

i Need to Write a function that takes a Node and checks if this node is the root of a binary search tree  ,if any one have the code for this problem or at least the algorithm.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions that give a programming problem and ask for a solution implementation aren't encouraged. Do you have example of code that you've tried. Please read [ask] for help asking good questions.

Comment: This is either theoretically impossible or too obvious (depends if you have a pointer to parent for example).

Comment: @Slava I don't think the question is about checking whether the note is a root; in a sense, every node is a root of *some* tree. The thrust of the question is likely to check whether a tree hanging off a given node meets the requirements of a binary search tree - a typical beginner's programming exercise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see, my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm needs to do in-order traversal and test whether the previous visited node is less-then-or-equal (or whatever the search tree predicate is) to the current node.